# Excel v.16 Using Selenium Basic for an Array on "div" Tags

Tags: html, arrays, excel, vba, selenium

I am **Web scraping** data from a **Chrome web page in Excel v.16** using **Selenium Basic**.
Because I am dealing with patient data, I cannot provide a lot of information.
(Originally, I wrote the code in VBA for IE.)

Here is the html:

[image]

Here is my **original VBA code**, which worked just fine:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Dim DIVS As Object
        Dim Div As Object
        Dim Num1 As Long
        Num1 = 0 'Initialize Num1

        Set DIVS = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("Div")

        For Each Div In DIVS    ' Loop through every input tag
                Num1 = Val(Div.innertext)    'Val function stops reading string at 1st character
                If Num1 > 0 _
                And Num1 < 10 Then
                        'data written to spreadsheet.
                End If
        Next Div
End With
```

In Selenium Basic I am finding it difficult to grab the “div” data.
I can access [image]  because it is an “id”.
But I need to know how to get the message elements within that “div id” (could be up to 10 messages) and load them into an array.

Messages I am referring to are:
[image]

Is there a way to accomplish using Selenium Basic what I did in VBA?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would help to post your existing Selenium code - should be pretty similar approach.

Comment: Does the DIV have children? If so, you can add another loop - For Each element in div.children. Then, get the innerText property of the children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Selenium, if you were to use the Chromedriver, it would look like this:

```
'Initialize Selenium
Dim Bot As WebDriver
Set Bot = New WebDriver

Bot.Start "chrome", "https://stackoverflow.com"
Bot.Get "/"

Dim DIVS As Object
Set DIVS = Bot.FindElementsByTag("div")

Dim Div As Object
Dim Num1 As Long
Num1 = 0 'Initialize Num1

For Each Div In DIVS    ' Loop through every input tag
        Num1 = val(Div.Text)    'Val function stops reading string at 1st character
        If Num1 > 0 _
        And Num1 < 10 Then
                'data written to spreadsheet.
        End If
Next Div
```

Note that to access the text inside the div, you would use:

```
Div.Text
```

inside the For-loop.